# I'm stuck. I checked the whole code and couldn't find any errors

Tags: python

Ok so basically, I'm making a program that allows me to list revision topics for my upcoming GCSEs. My code is shown below, but the txt file isn't being written to!!
If anyone has the time, I would also greatly appreciate it if you could tell me how to:
A) Make the "Need another topic" question infinite until the user says "n" (no)
B) Overwrite an existing file with the same name

CODE:

```
print("Which subject are we doing today?")
subject = input("Subject: ")
file = open(subject + " Revision Topics.txt", "w")
file.write("Here are a list of " + subject + " topics that need revising:\n")
print("Got topics to revise?")
intro = input("y or n: ")
if intro == "y":
    print("Which topic needs revising?")
    topic1 = input()
    print("Any more?")
    anotherone = input("y or n: ")
    if anotherone == "y":
        print("Which topic also needs revising?")
        topic2 = input()
        print("Any more?")
        anotherone = input("y or n: ")
        if anotherone == "y":
            print("Which topic also needs revising?")
            topic3 = input()
            print("Any more?")
            anotherone = input("y or n: ")
            if anotherone == "y":
                print("Which topic also needs revising?")
                topic4 = input()
                print("Any more?")
                anotherone = input("y or n: ")
                if anotherone == "y":
                    print("Which topic also needs revising?")
                    topic5 = input()
                    print("Any more?")
                    anotherone = input("y or n: ")
                    if anotherone == "y":
                        print("Which topic also needs revising?")
                        topic6 = input()
                        print("Any more?")
                        anotherone = input("y or n: ")
                        if anotherone == "y":
                            print("Which topic also needs revising?")
                            topic7 = input()
                            print("Any more?")
                            anotherone = input("y or n: ")
                            if anotherone == "y":
                                print("Which topic also needs revising?")
                                topic8 = input()
                                print("Any more?")
                                anotherone = input("y or n: ")
                                if anotherone == "y":
                                    print("Which topic also needs revising?")
                                    topic9 = input()
                                    print("You have reached the maximum number of topics.")
                                elif anotherone == "n":
                                    topic9 = ("")
                                else:
                                    print("Answer not recognised! :(")
                            elif anotherone == "n":
                                topic8 = ("")
                            else:
                                print("Answer not recognised! :(")
                        elif anotherone == "n":
                            topic7 = ("")
                        else:
                            print("Answer not recognised! :(")
                    elif anotherone == "n":
                        topic6 = ("")
                    else:
                        print("Answer not recognised! :(")
                elif anotherone == "n":
                    topic5 = ("")
                else:
                    print("Answer not recognised! :(")
            elif anotherone == "n":
                topic4 = ("")
            else:
                print("Answer not recognised! :(")
        elif anotherone == "n":
            topic3 = ("")
        else:
            print("Answer not recognised! :(")
    elif anotherone == "n":
        topic2 = ("")
    else:
        print("Answer not recognised! :(")
elif anotherone == "n":
    topic1 = ("")
file.write(topic1 + "\n" + topic2 + "\n" + topic3 + "\n" + topic4 + "\n" + topic5 + "\n" +topic6 + "\n" +topic7 + "\n" + topic8 + "\n" +topic9 + "\n")
```

file.close()
    print("Ok! So, " + subject + " Revision Topics.txt has been saved to the GCSE Revision folder under Documents.\n\nGood Luck Revising!")

END CODE

Thank you so much for helping, much appreciated <3

UPDATE: We've fixed the not saving issue, but now the error on the IDLE is telling me that topic9 is not defined? However I set a backup in an elif for topic9 to be defined as ""

Any ideas?

Comment: Is it really a minimal example of the problem you want solved?

Comment: You really need to learn about loops :)

Comment: You forgot to `file.close()`. Also, don't call variables `file`, there exists a standard module called like this, so here you're shadowing it.

Comment: Agree with @jpw, that `if`-tree kinda sucks mainly because such a structure is extremely hard to read and debug

Comment: @ForceBru I know I need to learn it, hence why I asked if someone could show me how... ;/  Thanks for the debug help

Comment: Use a loop, you want infinite times, but have hard coded just a few and then hit the "You have reached the maximum number of topics.". When ever you type the same thing more than once or twice, you need to think about using a loop there.

Comment: Thanks @Chuck I'll look into it on CodeCademy. Appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Use the magic of loops to solve your first problem.

```
print("Which subject are we doing today?")
subject = input("Subject: ")
wfile = open(subject + " Revision Topics.txt", "w")
wfile.write("Here are a list of " + subject + " topics that need revising:\n")
print("Got topics to revise?")
choice = input("y or n: ")
topics = []
while (choice != 'n'):
    print("Which topic needs revising?")
    topic = input()
    topics.append(topic)
    print("Any more?")
    choice = input("y or n: ")

wfile.write('\n'.join(topics))
wfile.close()
print("Ok! So, " + subject + " Revision Topics.txt has been saved to the GCSE Revision folder under Documents.\n\nGood Luck Revising!")
```

As for your second question, which part is not being written? Is the file being created at all? what if you run with administrator privilieges?

Comment: LEGEND. thank you so much, second question resolved by @ForceBru - forgot to file close duhhh!

Comment: I don't see how that was the problem.  Surely the file would be closed automatically when the program exits?

Comment: @JohnGordon Agreed, I only added the close since it's standard practice but I couldn't replicate the issue either. 
 
FreddieWorth, feel free to choose my answer as correct if it answered your question!

Answer (score 1):

In order to always make sure your file is closed correctly, it is often much better to use `with open(something) as name`:

```
with open(subject + " Revision Topics.txt", "w") as output_file:
    output_file.write("Here are a list of " + subject + " topics that need revising:\n")
    while True:
        output_file.write(input("Which topic needs revising?") + '\n')
        if input("Any more?") != "y":
            break
```

The above code will handle the opening, writing and closing of your file - using this method, you won't have to remember to close the file.